# How do I make a Mongo $in query that works for all of these?

Tags: php, mongodb

The query bellow finds a document with:

```
"tags" : [ { "a" : "a" } ]
```

But not:

```
"tags" : [ { "a" : "a", "b" : "b" } ]
```

So why not?

Here's the query:

```
$tag = "a";
$query['tags'] = array(
    '$in' => array(
        array(
            $tag => $tag
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: You are aware that tags: [ {'a': 'a', 'b': 'b'}] , is an array of only one element ?  Just making sure you didnt mean to make it an array of two elements.

Comment: Yes! This might be the problem.

Comment: Ok, when I make it an array of two elements it works fine for me.

Comment: So I need to have the document like [[{"a":"a"}], [{"b":"b"}]] ?

Answer (score 0):

@nadirsaghar

Actually, the following works fine

```
db.inventory.insert({tags: [ {'a':'a'}, {'b': 'b'}] });
db.inventory.find({tags: {$in: [ {'a': 'a'}]}});
```

Executing your query on that structure,

```
{ tags: { $in: ["a", "b"] } }
```

would fail.

So better put, the structure of the query used for $in must match what is being searched.  If tags were an array of single elements like ["a","b"] , your $in query must also search for single elements.  If searching for objects, the objects in the query would need to match objects in the array.

This assumes his initial tags was a typo and should read

```
"tags" : [ { "a" : "a"}, {"b" : "b" } ]
```